# Is possible to show an adColony ad in portrait mode?

Tags: air, adobe, portrait, ane, adcolony

I am using Adobe Air to develop an iOS portrait game.
Is possible to show an adColony ad in portrait mode?
Thanks,
Matias

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to view AdColony videos in portrait orientation on a phone.  On tablets, however, the orientation of our videos will follow your app's settings.